# JasperReport/Aspose.word - Background image working with pdf but doesn't with word

Tags: image, background, aspose.words

As explained in the title. I'm using aspose.word extension for JasperReports. When I create a report with the PDF format, everything works fine; but, when I export the same jrxml file in word .doc format I cannot see the background image.
I was wondering if aspose.word does support background images or not. I didn't manage to get this point in the documentation.

EDIT: It came out from Aspose Development Team that Aspose.word has a bug and actually doesn't show background images.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference for any one facing this issue in future. The issue with issue id:WORDSJSP-146 has been logged in our issue tracking system to fix this bug.

Also, following thread is posted in Aspose forum for the above issue http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/556318/background-image-not-showing.aspx.

P.S. I am social media developer at Aspose.